# Can not get array list from shared preference with error

Tags: android, arraylist, gson, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to upload users info from a recycler view to a shared preference and it works fine using this code

```
userInfoModelList.add(userInfo);
SharedPreferences userList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userList.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(userInfoModelList);
editor.putString("userList", json);
editor.apply();
```

---

but when I tried to run the emulator and called the load method to get the array from the shared preference using this code:

---

```
SharedPreferences userList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = userList.getString("userList", null);
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserInfoModel>>() {}.getType();
userInfoModelList= gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

---

I have got this error  and the emulator did not launch the app:

---

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:142)
>           at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:537)
>           at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:526)
>           at com.springmay.task4.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:58)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
>           at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)

---

MainActivity class

---

`

```
enter code here :public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddUserDialog.OnInputUserTypeListener {
FloatingActionButton addUserButton;

UserInfoRecycleAdapter userInfoRecycleAdapter;
RecyclerView userInfoRecycler;
Paint p = new Paint();
public ArrayList<UserInfoModel> userInfoModelList = new ArrayList<>();
boolean swipeBack = true;
SearchView searchView;
SearchManager searchManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initialize();
    fabListner();
   loadSavedUsers();
    setUpRecycler();

}

public void initialize() {
    addUserButton = findViewById(R.id.add_user);
    userInfoRecycler = findViewById(R.id.userInfoRecycler);
}

public void fabListner() {
    addUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AddUserDialog addUserDialog = new AddUserDialog("new");
            addUserDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    });

}



public void setUpRecycler() {
    userInfoRecycler.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this,
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    userInfoRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    userInfoRecycleAdapter = new UserInfoRecycleAdapter(MainActivity.this, userInfoModelList);
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchCallBack).attachToRecyclerView(userInfoRecycler);

    userInfoRecycler.setAdapter(userInfoRecycleAdapter);
}

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchCallBack =
        new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                  @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                    userInfoModelList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    userInfoRecycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

                    String phone = userInfoModelList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone();
                    String name = userInfoModelList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName();
                    String email = userInfoModelList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getEmail();
                    Bitmap photo = userInfoModelList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhoto();

                    UserInfoModel user = new UserInfoModel(name, email, phone, photo);

                    AddUserDialog addUserDialog = new AddUserDialog(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), user, "update");
                    addUserDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                    @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                    int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

                Bitmap icon;
                if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {

                    View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                    float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                    float width = height / 3;

                    if (dX > 0) {
                        p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#388E3C"));

                        RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft(),
                                (float) itemView.getTop(), dX, (float) itemView.getBottom());

                        c.drawRect(background, p);

                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pen);

                        RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() + width,
                                (float) itemView.getTop() + width, (float) itemView.getLeft() + 2 * width,
                                (float) itemView.getBottom() - width);

                        c.drawBitmap(icon, null, icon_dest, p);


                    } else {
                        p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));

                        RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX,
                                (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());

                        c.drawRect(background, p);

                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.x_button);
                        RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2 * width,
                                (float) itemView.getTop() + width, (float) itemView.getRight() - width,
                                (float) itemView.getBottom() - width);

                        c.drawBitmap(icon, null, icon_dest, p);


                    }
                }
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }


            @Override
            public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {

                if (swipeBack) {
                    swipeBack = false;
                    return 0;
                }
                return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
            }

        };


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            userInfoRecycleAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}


@Override
public void sendInputAdd(UserInfoModel userInfo) {


    userInfoModelList.add(userInfo);


        SharedPreferences userList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userList.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(userInfoModelList);
        editor.putString("userList", json);
        editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!

}

@Override
public void sendInputUpdate(int position, UserInfoModel userInfo) {

    userInfoModelList.add(position, userInfo);

}

public void loadSavedUsers() {
    SharedPreferences userList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = userList.getString("userList", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserInfoModel>>() {}.getType();
    userInfoModelList= gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

}`

---

Did I miss something?
I appreciate your kind ideas and solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: Where is `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this)` called from?

Comment: @Onik  its inside an implementation of interface  and the interface  inside the MainActivity .is this a wrong logic?

Comment: _"is this a wrong logic?"_ Yes. `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` should be called only when `Context` is created. A good place for that is `Activity`'s `onCreate()` for example

Comment: I will try it right now

Comment: it did not work :( but I edit my Q and added the mainActivity to be more specific and clear